# how to deploy website and a web API in the same VM

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-virtual-machine, azure-deployment

I have a azure VM, where I have deployed a website as a default web site. I have another Web API application which needs to deploy in the same VM to use the API for mobile app. Can I deploy the web API in the same VM?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sure, you just need to find a way to address the applications individually, because they probably listen to the same ports.

Comment: Can you describe little more? if you have anything in your mind

Comment: Yes you can, and you don't need another vm. One instance of IIS services can have and support and run several web sites. So, in IIS, just create a new web site, and folder. You can then publish your site to that new folder. So, it is quite common to have one instance of IIS, and it can run and support several web sites. About your only issue of course is that you have to give the site a different IP address, or at the very least use a different port number.  (and from IIS services, you can give that site a different port, or even a different IP address). url's have to include port number

Answer (score 0):

usually you have to have a router between applications, this can be a application load balancer which reroutes your traffic to the specific ports which your applications uses.

generally speaking if you are working with an application load balancer:

```
          [web.local.test:80]                                [web application:8081]
[user] =>                  => [Loadbalancer / Router] =>
          [api.local.test:80]                                [api application:8082]
```

This is a example how you can structure it (how i do it myself on AWS)

If you are running on a windows server you probably use IIS,

IIS example: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111219/how-can-i-configure-multiple-https-sites-on-one-iis-intranet-server-using-a-sing

If you run on a Unix VM you might use nginx or traefik.

Comment: I am using IIS. My website is running under default web site.

Comment: ok then you just have to configure a secondary web application in your IIS. so your default webapplication hast to work only on your web application domain and your api only on your api domain

Comment: @biks i added an example from stackexchange who had a similar problem hope it helps